# Evaluate the integral of $e^{x}/(x+1)^4$ on $\rho$, which denotes the entire imaginary axis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I'm not entirely sure if my intuition is correct but the singularity for this equation is -1 but -1 does not exist on the imaginary axis, so does this integral equal 0?

If not, what am I missing and can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

No: change variables to $ x= iy $. Then $i \, dy = dx$, and your integral is
$$I = i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iy}}{(y-i)^4} \, dy. $$
(This is not strictly speaking necessary, but it puts the integral in a more standard form.)

Now consider a semicircle in the upper half-plane, of radius $R>1$. Let $ \gamma_1 $ be the segment of the real axis between $ -R $ and $R$, and let the curved part of the semicircle be $\gamma_2$. Then by the residue theorem,
$$ i\int_{\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2} \frac{e^{iy}}{(1+iy)^4} \, dy = -2\pi \operatorname{Res}_i{\frac{e^{iy}}{(y-i)^4}}. $$
The integral over $\gamma_1$ tends to $I$ as $R \to \infty$, and the integral over $\gamma_2$ tends to zero by [Jordan's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).

Hence
$$ I = -2\pi \operatorname{Res}_i{\frac{e^{iy}}{(y-i)^4}},  $$
which is probably most easily calculated by finding the coefficient of $(y-i)^3$ in the Taylor expansion of $e^{iy}$ at $i$ (write $e^{iy} = e^{i(y-i+i)} = e^{-1} e^{i(y-i)} $ and so on to do it simply).

Comment: Why did you multiply the f(y) twice?  Doesn't residue at i already account for that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is when you take the Res(f,i) then you get the limit as z tends to i of (1/6 *d^{3}/dz^{3}*((y-i)^{4}*e^{iy}/(1+iy)^{4}) right?  I'm curious why you're multiplying e^{iy}/(1+iy)^{4} after finding the residue at i?  Can you perhaps right more explicitly the last step?  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that notation means the residue at $i$ of the following expression. It's just normally abbreviated somewhat.

Comment: Okay I got that now.  What do you mean by finding the taylor expansion of $e^{iy}$?

Comment: Same as usual. The residue is the coefficient of $(y-i)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion at $i$, and you can find the Laurent expansion by expanding $e^{iy}$ in a power series at $y=i$.

Comment: What's wrong with just taking the three derivatives as usual?  I mean with your method, we still arrive at $\pi i/3e$ right?